# bootstrap using styling similar to jquery.vgrid

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

need advise, can anyone help me to achieve styling similar to [jquery.vgrid](http://blog.xlune.com/2009/09/vgrid/demo007.html) with only using custom css on bootstrap?

seems bootstrap only provide [grid styling](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) which align horizontally, it can not adjust with custom height on adjacent grid.

I know I can still use jquery.vgrid plugin with bootstrap, but I wish to make it to compatible with mobile browser and reduce resizing calculation using javascript.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like isotope... is this what you want? http://mpezzi.github.io/bootstrap_isotope/#r/pics more info https://github.com/mpezzi/bootstrap_isotope

Comment: true, but isotope is seems using javascript to calculate grid positioning, I am aiming to only using css3 only, or it is not possible?

Comment: thanx JP Hellemons, your hint refer me to masonry, and here what I found http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/

Answer (score 0):

refer to comment above, JP Hellemons point to isotope which similar with masonry, and it can achieve using pure css

http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/